# drop multiple numpy axis's in array data

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that is (3, 3, 3, 64). I would like to eliminate data from two axis's of this array to get a (3, 3, 1, 64) array. I am sure there is a simple method of doing this, but I am not seeing it. I was hoping a numpy guru could point me in the right direction on how to do this.  I have tried something like this:

k = kernels[:, :, 0, :]

but that results in an array of (3, 3, 64), which is not what I want.

Comment: `kernetls[:,:,[0],:]`.  Indexing with a scalar removes the dimension  With a list or slice keeps it.

Comment: @hpaulj: that's more like an answer than a comment..

Comment: Better that than getting chastised for commenting in an answer.  That  can cost me points. :)  I'll let someone else write the answer version.

Comment: And... np.all(kernetls[:, :, 0:1, :] == kernetls[:, :, [0], :])  # True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup**

```
a = np.zeros((3, 3, 3, 64))
a.shape
Out[289]: (3L, 3L, 3L, 64L)
```

**Solution**

```
#Slice the array and reshape to desired shape
a_cut = a[:,:,0,:].reshape((3,3,1,64))

#check
a_cut.shape
Out[291]: (3L, 3L, 1L, 64L)
```

Or as hpaulj mentioned, you can use:

```
a[:,:,[0],:]
```